# how to submit text in a field without a submit button

Tags: jquery, forms, tampermonkey

Im searching and trying for some hours now and all i can find is how to submit a text that has a button for submiting, but i need to submit a text field that doesnt have a submit button, i cant post the link of the page because it needs login. But here is the code of the text field:

```
    <div class="items box module">
                <div class="title">
                    <input type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Type an item name or type and press enter!" />
```

The only way of sending it normally is pressing enter,i already searched for how to simulate a enter press but all i found was how to run something when you press enter. The only thing i managed to do so far is to put some text on it using:

```
    document.getElementById("filter").value = "test";
```

I need a way to select that field like if i had clicked on it and press enter to send it. Or other way to do that using code,already tried .click(); to select and .submit() to send but it wont work.

Im new to tampermonkey and java so sorry if im missing something obvious or asking something stupid.

Any help is welcome, Thanks very much

Comment: re reading my question now i think i forgot some details, the page is like a big list with multiple items where you type in this filter and press enter the list will change to the results containing what you typed (without refreshing or going to other page)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like: `document.getElementById("MyForm").submit();`

where `MyForm` is the id of the form where the actual textfield is in.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the input in a form, then when you type and hit enter it will submit automatically is that what you're trying to do?

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/egd54dsj/2/

```
 <div class="items box module">
                <div class="title">
                    <form id="filterForm">
                    <input type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Type an item name or type and press enter!" />
                    </form>
```

Function for submitting the form to validate or if you want to use ajax:

```
function submitForm() {
   console.log('form submit');
    return false;
};

document.getElementById('filterForm').addEventListener("submit", submitForm);
```

If you need a function when you click in the text input use:

```
function focus() {
 //
}
document.getElementById('filter').addEventListener("onfocus", focus);
```

Comment: thanks for the response, im trying to type and press enter automatically somehow, without actually having to press enter

Comment: I see, ok try something like this then and if you need a submit function for validation, etc follow the previous example for that listener: http://jsfiddle.net/egd54dsj/4/